# Set cell color in Excel based on text value - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, colors

I am writing a script to run `ping` on machines. The script looks to a text file with the hostnames, and returns the hostname in column A & the status of the `ping` (Up or Down) in column B.

I need the column B colors changed to Green if Up, and Red if Down.

Code with no issues:

```
'# call excel applicationin visible mode

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = True

objExcel.Workbooks.Add

intRow = 2


'# Define Labels 

objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Machine Name"

objExcel.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Results"


'# Create file system object for reading the hosts from text file


Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set InputFile = fso.OpenTextFile("MachineList.Txt")

'# Loop thru the text file till the end 

Do While Not (InputFile.atEndOfStream)

HostName = InputFile.ReadLine

'# Create shell object for Pinging the host machines

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Ping = WshShell.Run("ping -n 1 " & HostName, 0, True)


objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value = HostName

'# use switch case for checking the machine updown status

Select Case Ping

Case 0 objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = "up"

Case 1 objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = "down"

End Select


intRow = intRow + 1

Loop

'# Format the excel

objExcel.Range("A1:B1").Select

objExcel.Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 19

objExcel.Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 11

objExcel.Selection.Font.Bold = True

objExcel.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

What I have tried for color (many issues):

```
Sub ColorCells()
     Dim cel As Range
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Application.EnableEvents = False
     For Each cel In Range("B2:B90")
         Select Case LCase(Left(cel.Value, 1))
             Case "up"
                 cel.Interior.Color = vbGreen
             Case Else
                 cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
         End Select
     Next cel
     Application.EnableEvents = True
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

What I get:

[image: What I get]

What I want:

[image: What I want]

Comment: Straight away I see the your code does not start or end with `Sub`   `End Sub` except for the `Sub ColorCells()` so It does not even work on my side. What you want to do also is to reference the `Sheet` when using `Range` otherwise I believe that it will perform the action on the active sheet. Is there some code you have left out?

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen No code was left out. I have just pieced together things and this is the closest I have got to accomplishing the goal. I am new to VBA.

Comment: Your code has so many issues that is difficult to even know where to start 

    Select Case LCase(Left(cel.Value, 1))
                 Case "Down"
If you lower case a value it will never be equal to "Down" with a capital D
SO start small, line by line and run the code and add stuff

Comment: If I remove the Sub, the code runs with no issues. I am not aware of how to correct the Sub's issues (up to objExcel.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit).
I tried only running the code with "up" no caps and only 1 Case to see if I could get Green to work, with no success.

Comment: I have updated what I have tried so far and attempted to clarify.

Comment: does your code fill column B up correctly? is your issue the coloring of correct values only? if so, what's the result of you `ColorCells()` code?

Comment: @user3598756 Yes, the columns fill up with text with no issues. The issue is that I can't apply color to the cells programmatically. The ColorCells() code does nothing.

Comment: `Case LCase(Left(cel.Value, 1))` will just check the first letter. Try `Case LCase(Left(cel.Value, 2))` to check for the first two letters.

Comment: @BruceWayne This worked! I added it as a Module in Excel. Any suggestions for incorporating into the .vbs script itself? Or a way this would run simultaneously?

Comment: What you can do is add the color changing line to the `Case 0` and `Case 1` so basically it will add the "up" or "down" text and then change the color of the cell straight after. Otherwise, if it is just for visual indication you can have **Conditional Formatting** for those cells which is look at the content and then change to color accordingly.

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen Your first idea is perfect, but I have tried many things to no avail. Could you provide some examples of your concept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the color of the cell as you insert the "up" or "down" just replace the `Select Case Ping` with the following:

```
Select Case Ping

Case 0
    objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = "up"
    objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Interior.Color = vbGreen
Case 1
    objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = "down"
    objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Interior.Color = vbRed

End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Case Ping

Case 0 objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = "up"
    objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Interior.Color = vbGreen

Case 1 objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = "down"
    objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Interior.Color = vbRed

End Select
```

This would be how to implement the colour within the select Case statement. Look below at my use of `With` though as it is a much better method than using `.Select` (instead of your final lines of code in the question):

```
With objExcel.Range("A1:B1")
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 19
    .Font.ColorIndex = 11
    .Font.Bold = True
End With

objExcel.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```